# New oven still puts out terrible odor 5 days after buying?

Tags: oven, microwave, smell

I recently bought a new convection oven/microwave/grill combo made by Sharp. The user manual said for first time use to run the convection oven at max heat (230C) for 1 hour, which produced a verybad odor but I felt like this was normal. Now, even 5 days later, after cook several frozen pizzas/french fries/bacon and other good stuff, the oven still produces a bad odor when in use.

Can something be done about this or should I expect it to go away after some more time?

Here's the exact oven combo if you're curious, https://sharp.vn/vn/index.php/thiet-bi-gia-dung/lo-vi-song/dong-dien-tu/299/r-c951dvn-st-1-detail

Comment: [Similar complaint](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/49922/when-does-the-new-home-oven-stove-smell-go-away) for GE ovens.

Comment: My countertop Kitchen Aid convection oven didn't smell great for a few days but wasn't that bad. (And I'm sensitive to chemicals). It's a pity that manufacturers don't avoid using plastics in appliances that heat. Hopefully yours is getting better soon.

Comment: @padma so you figure it's a waiting game? Hoping the odor will decrease over time and use? So manufacturers actually put in plastics that are melting and putting out this smell?

Comment: @trying_hal9000 : it could be any volatile organic chemical (VOC).  Epoxy or other adhesive, solvents, etc.

Comment: @trying_hal9000 hopefully time will help. And I think it's more like what Joe said, not necessarily plastic but smells like it.

Answer (score 3):

It is a normal experience that every time you use a new appliance with a heating device, you will smell something weird like burning plastic. I recommend you to read on the link below on some tips of getting rid of chemical residue (smell) from your new oven.

https://www.cnet.com/how-to/why-you-should-always-burn-in-your-new-oven/

If this is not effective, try my experiment which did a great wonder. Pour some water into a pan and add a teaspoonful of cinnamon powder into it, put inside the oven and set it to 250°C. You may also use a tablespoonful of vinegar as a substiyute.

Comment: +1 for water, would be my answer. Except, while vinegar or citric acid is something I would suggest (food safe and helps with cleaning and self-cleaning), I disagree with cinnamon powder. It will mask odour, not really get rid of it. And you really want to truly get rid of these - if it smells bad, it is probably not great for your health, right? That said, water plus some mild food acid is the way that worked for me in the past, both with new devices and (more often) with devices that got dirty later.

Comment: It seems that in more recent years more and more appliances smell like plastic. It wasn't always like this. Not great for peoples' health.